# Data driven dots coloring in scatter chart?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use color instead of labels in a scatter chart?

For example, use those brands from third column as colors to distinguish the dots.

```
| Mileage | Price |  Brand   |
|---------|-------|----------|
|  165000 | $4500 | Honda    |
|  220000 | $3000 | Subaru   |
|  175000 | $5200 | Kawasaki |
|  195000 | $4500 | Honda    |
|   90000 | $7500 | Kawasaki |
|  122000 | $6600 | Honda    |
```

To achieve this: [Data driven scatter coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gexD3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more control over the size of the markers with a scatter plot, but for that a different layout may be more convenient for the charting:

[image: SO46412328 second example]

I left the `Subaru` at the default 7 pixels but shrunk the other two series to 2 pixels.

Comment: It requires a little fuss with input data arrangement, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Might be other ways to do so but I used a bubble chart:

[image: Bubble chart]

The right hand column is for scaling the dots.

Comment: Is there any way to make the dots/bubbles smaller? I can't make them smaller then those.